# Why queue using two stacks not functioning?

Tags: c, stack, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue using 2 stacks but my code isn't functioning.

Can you spot the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5

typedef struct stack {
  int top;
  int arr[MAX];
} stack;

void enque(stack*s1, int ele) {
  printf("entering");
  push(&s1, ele);
  printf("what a pain");
}

void push(stack*s, int ele) {
  if (s->top == MAX - 1) {
    printf("OVERFLOW");
  } else {
    s->arr[++s->top] = ele;
  }
}

int deq(stack*s1, stack*s2) {
  int x;
  if (s1->top == -1 && s2->top == -1) {
    printf("empty");
  } else {
    if (s2->top == -1) {
      while (s1->top != -1) {
        push(&s2, pop(&s1));
      }
    }
    x = pop(&s2);
    return x;
  }
}

int pop(stack *s) {
  if (s->top == -1) {
    printf("UNDERFLOW");
  } else {
    return s->arr[s->top--];
  }
}

void display(stack*s) {
  printf("entered display");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= s->top; i++) {
    printf(" %d", s->arr[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
  int ch, ele, c;
  stack s1, s2;
  s1.top = -1, s2.top = -1;
  do {
    printf("1 - Enqueue2-deq3-display4-exit\n");
    printf("Enter choice");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch (ch) {
      case 1:
        printf("enter ele of ur choice");
        scanf("%d", &ele);
        enque(&s1, ele);
        break;
      case 2:
        c = deq(&s1, &s2);
        printf("%d", c);
        break;
      case 3:
        display(&s1);
        break;
      case 4:
        exit(0);
      default:
        printf("Wrong choice");
    }
  } while (ch != 5);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, list the error and things you have tried. The question as its stands is not understandable.

Comment: im new and i dont no  how to  submit my code?can u pls tell me how to do it

Comment: I deleted your `ender code here` that was at the beginning of each line. Then I highlighted your code and pressed the {} button above the text box to indicate that what I had selected was code and not text. Please read the documentation on how to post a question. We are not here to do work for you.

Comment: your question is still not answerable as it stands.

Comment: sorry and thnx..basically im getting a segmentation fault when i press case 1 that is basically enque its suppose to push an element onto stack 1 but my s1 top isnt incrementing it enters enque and then its suppose to  add the element onto s1 because of the push function being called butits showing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you spot the error?

The compiler can spot the error faster than Stack-overflow.

**OP is not compiling with all warnings enabled  or is using a weak compiler**

Enable all warnings to save time.

---

`int deq(stack*s1, stack*s2)` and `int pop(stack *s)` both have the same problem.

A common waning in such cases is `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Make certain each function path returns a value.

```
int pop(stack *s) {
  if (s->top == -1) {
    printf("UNDERFLOW");  // Notice, no return
  } else {
    return s->arr[s->top--];
  }
}
```

---

Also `push(&s1, ele);` used before declaration.  This make for conflicting function signature.  Declare or define `push()` before using.  Likely *undefined behavior* (UB) and this makes the code unreliable.

---

I  recommend to print an `'\n'` more often.

```
// printf("entering");
printf("entering\n");
// or
puts("entering");  // \n automatically added.
```

Comment: i rectified all the errors u said but it still dosent add the element to the stack

Comment: @user10598529 Append to the post 3 things: data entered, results seen and the results expected.

Comment: @user10598529 "i rectified all the errors" unfortunately did not include the first fix: enabling all warnings.  Else you would have certainly been warned about `push(&s1, ele);`.

Comment: can u pls tell me the error with regards to my push operation just elaborate on it

Answer (score 0):

You are passing pointer address in `deque` and `enque` functions.

`push(&s2, pop(&s1)); --> push(s2, pop(s1));
     x = pop(&s2); --> x = pop(s2);
     push(&s1, ele);-->push(s1, ele);`

since `s1` and `s2` are received as pointers to `deque` and `enque` functions

---

Also consider changes suggested by @[Mr.Chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) by considering compiler warnings you could have resolved all the issues by yourself.

Comment: hi can u pls elaborate more on the first point  u said a bit more explaining why my code is wrong since by doing what you said in the first point makes  my code work..im a little confused when it comes to using pointers in data structures...

Comment: and the second point u wrote is when i make the enque  more costly then we push it back from stack 2 to stack one else if my dequeu operation is more costly then this is the right method it is less time consuming

Comment: @user10598529 Answering your first question. You pass address of `s1 and s2` from main `c = deq(&s1, &s2);` that is you are passing them as pointers. Hence `int deq(stack*s1, stack*s2) ` `s1 and s2` in deque are pointer variables      . When you do this  `push(&s2, pop(&s1));` you are passing address of `s1 and s2` that is pointer to pointer.

Comment: @user10598529 Answering your second question. Right you are. I completely misread your code. Your approach is efficient.